# PyCharm vertical edit: Looking for Visual Studio equivalent of Alt key for selecting multiple lines

Tags: pycharm

In Visual Studio, we can hold down the `Alt` key and select multiple lines together...

e.g: here I am changing the indentation of 3 lines together:

[image]

How can I do the same in PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a documentation on their website you can find that here

https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/feature-spotlight-multiple-selections-in-pycharm/

If you are using a windows machine, it may work with `alt or shift`

In case of MAC it works with `option` key

Comment: Thanks for this... alt + mouse click on required lines worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to click and **drag**, then change your key bindings this way:

In **Preferences > Keymap > Editor Actions** set

`Create Rectangular Selection on Mouse Drag` to `⌥ Click`  (clears old cursors)

Note that it should be **Create** instead of **Add**, and if you like you could set

`Add Rectangular Selection on Mouse Drag` to `⌥ ⇧ Click`  (keeps old cursors)